# ie only stylesheet not working, code included

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I coded a website, and obviously when uploaded it to test it, its messing up in IE.

Im trying to insert an IE only stylesheet, but its not working, the code I have is:

```
<!--[if IE]>        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ieonly.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Whats going wrong?

Any one can help me, that would be amazing?

On IE everything is getting mis aligned.

Comment: Is the IE stylesheet not being applied at all? Or are your IE-only corrections not working how you want? If the second is true, we need to see code.

Comment: Is the path to your file correct, it's not in any directory? This stylesheet should be loaded AFTER your general stylesheet.

Comment: Inspect the elements which should have their styles changed via the `ieonly.css` file. F12 will bring it up depending on the version of IE you are using.

Comment: Niels, you were right, it was before my original stylesheet. please make this an answer so i can accept. thanks everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well your syntax seems ok.Try using the developer toolbar to check if the path to your CSS file is right

```
<!--[if IE]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```