# IE only css not loading

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

It is very simple HTML page which I am trying to render on IE 11 but somehow never takes the IE specific css file.

I am attaching my code here.

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico">

    <title>Demo</title>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if IE]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/all-ie-only.css" />
    <![endif]-->

  </head>
  <body class="subpage">

  </body>
</html>
```

And my css contains :

**style.css**

```
body{background:blue;}
```

**all-ie-only.css**

```
body{background:red;}
```

**Note :**
I already referred and tried solution from similar question like below with no luck.

[ie only stylesheet not working, code included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169571/ie-only-stylesheet-not-working-code-included)

**Solution I tried with no luck :**

```
<script>
/*@cc_on

  @if (@_jscript_version == 11)
    document.write("You are using IE11 with an older document mode");
  @elif (@_jscript_version == 10)
    document.write("You are using IE10");
  @elif (@_jscript_version == 9)
    document.write("You are using IE9");
  @elif (@_jscript_version == 5.8)
    document.write("You are using IE8");
  @elif (@_jscript_version == 5.7 && window.XMLHttpRequest)
    document.write("You are using IE7");
  @elif (@_jscript_version == 5.6 || (@_jscript_version == 5.7 && !window.XMLHttpRequest))
    document.write("You are using IE6");
  @elif (@_jscript_version == 5.5)
    document.write("You are using IE5.5");
  @elif (@_jscript_version < 5.5)
    document.write("You are using a version older than IE5.5");
  @else
    document.write("You are using an unknown version of IE");
  @end

@*/
</script>
```

What I have tried with is as suggested here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment

It seems, it never gets into if conditions specifying "@_jscript_version". Any help futher appreciated.

Comment: As marked this question duplicated with "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27470022/if-conditional-statement-not-working-with-ie-11" link, I couldn't find solution to my problem from this. It has some confusing answer which lead me nowhere and I am still stuck.

Comment: check the link in the accepted answer in the duplicate question. It clearly states that IE10+ no longer has conditional statement support. All IE sees now is a commented block of HTML, so it will not parse it. You will have to use a different way to get things done, also explained in the other question.

Comment: I clearly understood that the IE10+ no longer supports conditional statement but I also specified that no solution was found for my issue. I already checked around and tried various solution. But nothing works. Check my comment on first answer of this question.

Comment: If you're getting stuck on other solutions, please edit the question with the specific problems you're having with those solutions. As it currently stands, this question is still a duplicate of existing questions.

Answer (score 4):

IE10 and IE11 do not support conditional comments.

> Conditional comments are no longer supported in IE10 and IE11.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried mentioned code on this page but it doesn't work for me somehow. It seems, it never gets into if conditions specifying "@_jscript_version". Any help can you offer further?